# Windows 7 how to make explorer open a file with a vbs script

Tags: java, vbscript

I am running openjdk on windows 7 without admin rights

I went through the explorer "open-with" dialogue to select java as the program to "open" the .jar file.
To run a .jar file by (double) click, windows executes something like

> java (filename).jar

However, java requires the argument -jar, i.e.:

> java -jar (filename).jar

To set this up the user needs admin rights to use assoc and ftype,

or implement the register edits as explained in the answer below.

Another workaround is to use a batch file, e.g. javastart.bat:

Listing javastart.jar

```
start java -jar %1
```

After going through the explorer "open with" dialogue, this works.
Clicking the jar file will open the command window and this will start java.

However, while java is running, the command-window is also open, which is ugly.

**Edit**

javaw.exe must be called, and the command-windows will close:

```
start javaw.exe -jar %1
```

the following script is not needed to close the command window

**End of edit**

To resolve this, I start a vbs script.

New listing javastart.jar

```
start startjar.vbs %1
```

And startjar.vbs:

```
Set args = Wscript.Arguments
cmd = "java -jar " & chr(34) & args(0) & chr(34)
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run cmd, 0, True
```

This works: now I get a short flash of the command window starting the vbs, and then the windowless vbs-script starts java and the jar-file.

However, when I directly open the jar file with startjar.vbs, (right click the jar file, than go through the open with dialogue), the name of the jar file is not passed as an argument to the vbs, but windows tries to run the jar file directly (and gives an error: "the .jar file is not a valid win32-application").

Why is windows explorer not sending the filename as an argument to the vbs script?

Comment: *To set this up the user needs admin rights...* is not true. Setting under `HKCR` come from both `HKCU\Software\Classes` and `HKLM\Software\Classes`. You can certainly edit `HKCU` settings as they are yours.

Comment: May be true, but which setting should be edited? The following edit (after "a") seems not to work : [HKEY_USERS\....\Explorer\FileExts\.jar\OpenWithList]
"a"="java.exe -jar"
"MRUList"="bca"
"b"="startjar.bat"
"c"="startjar.vbs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting under HKCR come from both HKCU\Software\Classes and HKLM\Software\Classes. You can certainly edit HKCU settings as they are yours. If they exist they override the exact same HKLM settings. Under HKCR you will see a merged view of both with CU overriding any LM settings.

This started off as notepad's settings. **Fix the path to your javaw.exe file**.

jar files are now on the New menu, are searched by windows search, treated as text files so edit on right click menu but open as a program file.

If you are a non-admin use the reg command to merge (**after fixing the path**). If you are an admin double-click it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile]
@="Java Program File"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Folder\\javaw.exe -jar \"%1\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.jar]
@="jarfile"
"Content Type"="text/plain"
"PerceivedType"="text"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.jar\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.jar\ShellNew]
"ItemName"=hex(2):6a,00,61,00,72,00,66,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,00,00
"NullFile"=""
```

Comment: Yes, this workaround opens the jarfile with the command java -jar. However, the  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Folder\\java -jar \"%1\""
seems to open the 'ugly' command (shell) windows as well...

Comment: I don't use Java but is not Java the non console version and Javac the console version.

Comment: javac is the java compiler (and java is the virtual machine in which compiled java files can run)

Comment: There are two types of programs. Graphical (windows doesn't give them a console automatically but they can create one themselves) and console (windows starts the program with a console). I've never seen Java. So I don't know what it's exe is. There is nothing I posted that forces a console to be created. It's all up to a flag in Java.exe's header how it behaves.

Comment: If you are getting a console make sure there are no `java.bat` hanging about.

Comment: As test I replaced [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell\open\command] @="C:\\Folder\\java -jar \"%1\" by@="C:\\portable-tools\\notepad2\\notepad2.exe \"%1\""
no shell opens indeed.

Comment: There is java.exe and javaw.exe. Starting with java opens the shell, starting with javaw not, so the key must read @=" C:\\java\\jdk-11.0.1\\bin\\javaw.exe -jar "%1"" and it starts without shell. Thx!